# How to run a thread in a web worker powered by a multi threaded WebAssembly module created by Emscripten?

Tags: multithreading, webassembly, emscripten

I'm developing a search engine that should compile both under Visual Studio and to WebAssembly using Emscripten ( [cengine](https://github.com/easychessanimations/cengine) ). The core code works very well. The WebAssembly module runs within a web worker, and commands issued using the HTML input of the page are sent as a message to this worker, which has a Javascript message handler that invokes the necessary funcion of the WebAssembly module using cwrap.

However I'm having problem when I want to use an extra thread in the WebAssembly code, so that during search the worker remains responsive to incoming commands.

My build command is this:

```
emcc src/attack.cpp src/bitboard.cpp src/cengine.cpp src/matein4.cpp src/piece.cpp src/search.cpp src/square.cpp src/state.cpp -s WASM=1 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=30MB -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=1 -D WASM -o wasmbuild/cengine.html -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_main','_execute_uci_command']" -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="['cwrap']"
```

This compiles without problem. The web worker runs, and when the worker tries to invoke a the search thread, instead of executing the code, I get a message in my message handler like:

```
{cmd: "run", start_routine: 11, arg: 0, threadInfoStruct: 25501264, selfThreadId: 25501264, …}
arg: 0
cmd: "run"
parentThreadId: 2295120
selfThreadId: 25501264
stackBase: 23404096
stackSize: 2097152
start_routine: 11
threadInfoStruct: 25501264
time: 3276.1050000008254
__proto__: Object
```

So normally when the module is loaded, Emscripten adds a web worker to start a thread, generates a separate output file for this, but I already use the module as a web worker and I get the message that this Emscripten generated code should.

I'm lost what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I used the code in a worker for responsiveness in the first place, as a worker runs in a true thread and does not block the application main thread.

However if you use Emscripten pthread, then this is taken care for you, so you can move back the code to the app instead spawning it in a worker. So you include the glue code that Emscripten generates in the index.html ( which is the default by the way ).

What happened is that I used a make shift solution to a problem, for which a proper solution exists, and once you use the proper solution, this conflicts with your make shift solution. Emscripten essentially handles the worker creation by itself if you direct it in the build command by switches `-s USE_PTHREADS=1 -s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=2`.